# Module not found error although __init__.py file is in every folder. What is missing?

Tags: python, import, path

I have a project that has several folders inside the project folder where classes were defined.
Folder structure is as follows :

```
--> model (folder)
    - model1 (file)
    - model2 (file)
--> setup (folder)
    --  __init__.py (file)
    --  load_model.py
    --> utils (folder)
        -- __init__.py (file)
        -- utilities.py (file)
--  setup.py (file)
--  __init__.py (file)
--  inference.py (file)
```

load_model.py is as follows --> (few lines)

```
from utils.utilities import *
import cv2
```

inference.py file is as follows (few lines)

```
from setup.load_model import *
```

When I run 'inference.py', I get the error that

```
No module named 'utils'
```

at `from utils.utilities import *` line in utilities.py file.

Although I have included **init**.py (empty) in each folder, the system does not recognize utils as the folder located in the setup file.

Any help with this error ? (If I keep the utils folder in root, this works fine anyway)

Comment: I just wonder whether your _ _ initi _ _.py is a misstype in this question only, or also in your folder too

Comment: Good catch, it's a mistake. I corrected it,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but updating the following line

```
from utils.utilities import *
```

to

```
from .utils.utilities import *
```

fixed the issue. There is a '.' at the beginning of the 'utils'.